# How to fix a timer issue

Tags: python, timer

i am a biginner at this.  and i am talking about a,b,c beginner.  i am taking a class and i'm on a project i am compeltely stuck on.  i wrote this code and it seams to be working ok except not accurately.  i think i have to rewrite this whole code but thought i'd try you guys before i do.  that's the only option i was given by my peers :(

=== deleted ====

this makes my timer work but not correctly.  my problem is that as you can see the incrementation by 1 starts the same time the other variable is at 0.  well this makes the clock go off because 9 and 0 happen at the same time.  what can i do inside this code to make sure that  + 1 happenes AFTER x y or z are at 0 for the full mill second?  i've tried a few things.  nothing is working there are limited things i have access to (in time (only have acess to time.time()), math etc modules) so i hope your answers will be truely elementary.

i hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language this is about.

Comment: what language is this? and what are you trying to accomplish? format the time value so it looks like `00:00:00`?

Comment: oh sorry.  this is python.  and it's supposed to look like 0:00.0.  making a stopwatch.  if it makes any diff. all my cosmetic stuff is fine.  only the mechanics are my issue.

Comment: Could you post the entire code? cause i have no clue what `timer` is.. and how and what x is being used..

Comment: i'd get in trouble :s  ... but i understand if you can't help me otherwise.  but if i can answer your Q 
the timer looks like this -- 0:00.0 ---- 
x: y y1.z ---
that's what corresponds to what in the code above.

Comment: @Bianca i just wrote a answer below (see the second example) which is accurate down to 1/1000 of a second. Should be good enough to make a timer.

Comment: @Bianca also, my last edit shows how to create a timer, counting the time since started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
import datetime

class timer():
    def start(self):
        while 1:
            x = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            print(x.strftime('%M.%S.%f'))
            time.sleep(0.1)

worker = timer()
worker.start()
```

That does the work.
Note that the accuracy of Python is quite limited, if you want to get a more perfect timer you would have to store the last known millisecond (1/1000 of a second) and create a `while 1` loop to wait for exactly the correct ammount of time and then release and continue with the endless loop within `start()`.

Something along the lines:

## This will print Current time

```
import time
import datetime

def getTime():
    return int(round(time.time() * 1000))

class timer():
    def start(self):
        lastRun = getTime()
        while 1:
            while getTime() - lastRun < 100:
                pass
            lastRun = getTime()
            x = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            print(x.strftime('%M.%S.%f'))

worker = timer()
worker.start()
```

This is about as accurate as you can get with Python.
And to the explaining part:

`x = datetime.datetime.utcnow()` will store the current time in a variable called `x` obviously. In python, variables are "objects" with functions.. and this particular variable as a function called `strftime` inside it.
`strftime` takes a few parameters and will convert the current time into a string that you want to be able to read, in this case we will create `%M` for minutes, followed by a dot and then `%S` for seconds and finally a dot followed by `%f` which is miliseconds.
And ofcourse it's based on your current time, if you need to count how long something has been running, you can add `time.time() - self.time` into one of `datetime.datetime` functions instead of `utcnow()`, and so it will count how long something's been running.

## And this is a stopwatch

```
import time
import datetime

def getTime():
    return int(round(time.time() * 1000))

class timer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = datetime.datetime.today()

    def start(self):
        lastRun = getTime()
        while 1:
            while getTime() - lastRun < 100:
                pass
            lastRun = getTime()
            x = datetime.datetime.today() - self.time
            print(x)

worker = timer()
worker.start()
```

The code is almost identical, the only difference is the use of `self.time` which stores the "startup time", we will subtract `now` with `startup time`, so the operation would be:

- store startup
- for each loop, get "now"
- now-startup=ammount of time running
- print the result, it will automaticly be formatted as "0:00:01.800000"

Comment: thank you very much for this explanation.  these are the things we are going towards and maybe i now have an upper hand knowing this. i can't use it now because i don't have acess to datetime module. i thank you so much for your time! you guys are GREAT!

Comment: You're welcome, and sorry for a blurry and not so in depth explanation of the code, sitting on a train-ride home.. DC every 2 minutes :)
Anyways, don't forget to mark one of the answers as "correct" (green tick under the voting thing).. it gives us other users pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

This is your code modified to increment correctly, and display like a psuedo-timer (minutes, seconds, and 1/10ths of a sec).
Note that this isn't a true timer, as it takes just about a second to simulate 5 minutes of time incrementation. (Torxed's answer implements a true timer.)

```
fsec = 0
sec = 0
minute = 0

while (minute < 5):
    fsec += 1
    if fsec == 10:
        fsec = 0
        sec += 1
        if sec == 60:
            sec = 0
            minute += 1
    print str(minute) + ":" + str(sec) + "." + str(fsec)
```

Comment: i tried this straight to see how it does.  i get TimeLimitError: Program exceeded run time limit. at fsec += 1. i'll play with it and make it work. but also going to look at the code though more thoroughly and see its workings and perhaps apply them to my own code. that way i'd be learning and not taking.  
thank you guys sooo much for taking the time to help me on this.  i seriously appreciate it!